Why is the term "card" used in "expansion card"?
I'm curious about the historical origin of the use of the word "card" in "expansion card."
"Expansion board" makes sense, given it's a PCB, and a PCB is a board (of fibreglass for example).
But "card" seems a bit esoteric. Did this terminology originate from the physical resemblance to punch cards, index cards, or something else - possibly simply the fact they're rectangular and most type of cards are too!?

FWIW I personally knew about "expansion cards" before I ever heard of a PCB or knew what a PCB was, so perhaps it was coined by someone who was not knowledgable about electronics. To me, "card" is the opposite of esoteric - everyone knows what cards are, while "PCB" is electronics jargon.

To me "board" and "card" are equally nonesoteric but a card is smaller than a board. That's why we don't play poker with boards while sitting on the floorcards.

Interestingly, in French, we use "carte" (card) even for a motherboard (carte mère), but also, like in English, for graphics cards, network cards, expansion cards...

@jcaron at risk of drifting too far off topic, card came into English from French while board came in from Germanic so it makes sense French would have a broader lexical scope for card.

I'm not sure that "PCB" has much to do with it. I do a little hobby electronics, and a PCB is merely one component of a thing, and not the name of the finished thing, nor even a contributor to the name. (The thing is called a "module", not a card, in my use-case).

Perhaps the word "card" has a broader meaning than you appreciate. Punch cards, index cards, playing cards, etc are all examples of "a usually rectangular piece of stiff paper, thin pasteboard, or plastic for various uses" (Dictionary.com).  So are the kind of cards you are talking about.

TL;DR: It was cardboard and equal sized at first
'Boards' of various size and style are a later development.


I'm curious about the historical origin of the use of the word "card" in "expansion card."

Asking for a 'why' when it's about language is rarely useful. Still, in this case it can be said that "card" existed even before it was used for expansions :))

"Expansion board" makes sense, given it's a PCB, and a PCB is a board (of fibreglass for example).

Well except that early cards were not PCBs, as the first generation didn't carry any circuit, especially not a 'printed' one, nor were they fiberglass, but made of resin soaked paper.
PCBs as we know today underwent a long development. Electronics started with frames mounting components connected by wires and other components, called point-to-point, a technology taken from previous radio design, as seen here:

(Taken from Wikipedia)
Early computers were built the same way except, due to their repetitive nature, a more structured modular approach was possible. See this IBM Module used in 700 series mainframes in the 1950s:

(Taken from this CHM page)
There is nothing even close to a PCB here. As early as the 1920s the first radio equipment manufacturers started using early forms of circuit board made from resin-soaked and pressed paper. But those boards did not feature any traces, nor any other components - only holes to hold wired components. This use solved a major problem of point-to-point wiring by keeping wires and components apart from each other by a non-conductive carrier.
The first circuit board with wires embedded showed up as early as the 1900s (even Edison tried to build some). They were ahead of their time: there was no real need, as the few components that made up a radio or similar did do well without. In areas where complexity and density were required, there was some limited use. Even some multilayer boards were used by German manufacturers during the war. Neither were of much influence for early computing (*1)
In radios, PCBs started to appear in Europe during the late 1930s/early 40s, while the US still held the technology a war secret until 1949, somewhat slowing development. It wasn't until the mid 1950s that the first PCBs were used in computers. Although DEC's flip-chip modules are not amongst the earliest examples, they may be the best-known ones:

(Taken from Wikipedia)
Since they were targeted at a low price point, they show many features of earlier boards (and quite low density). From there to today's 20+ layer and 50µm trace size was still a very long way.

But "card" seems a bit esoteric. Did this terminology originate from the physical resemblance to punch cards, index cards, or something else - possibly simply the fact they're rectangular and most type of cards are too!?

Rather from simply being just cards made of paper. There's no need to borrow any meaning from other media.

Early machines were built from cards of equal size connected not by a 'motherboard' but wired backplane.
The next step after wired backplanes was bus systems using PCBs. (*2)
Motherboards only came after that with smaller, rather desktop style machines. (*3)

In fact it's, pretty much the reverse of your assumption: being called 'board' is a result of distinguishing them, as the main unit, from cards, which are parts thereof.

*1 - One notable intermediate step for complex boards, used especially on the Allied side, were boards holding riveted rows of solder points. Its use in several US products of the late 1940s was due to the fact that the US considered PCBs a war secret, and only released in 1949.

(Taken from Wikipedia)
*2 - Thin S100 or ECB.
*3 - The notable difference between motherboards and earlier incarnations of backplanes is that a motherboard contains active components, often quite expensive ones like CPU, Memory and/or basic I/O. Back in the early days no one would have put either on a fixed layer burrowed under everything else. Not just because of the size needed, but also as cost in case of failure would have killed any company, regardless of size. It only became a thing when most components of a machine became small enough to fit on a single reasonable-sized board.

I've never heard the word 'card' in conjunction with electronic construction using tag strips and turret boards, even if the base was a card-and-resin composite. So that part of connection history, though interesting, does not seem to cast much light on when/why a flat thing with interconnected components got to be called a 'card'.

@dave Nor have I said that they were called 'card' - or did I say so? That part explains the history of PCB. Point is that they were from card board as well as having existed as with parts and wires but before PCBs having wires printed on. And last but not least reassembled play cards due their uniform size. What else to call them?

Early usage of 'card' to refer to PCBs (year 1958): The IBM 7070 data processing system figure 5.

"What else to call them?" They were called 'tag strips' and 'turret boards' !

@jpa - speculation: 'card' and 'mainframe' evolved together.   A card (or assembly of cards) needs a frame to hold them.  The main frame, of course, is the one holding the control and arithmetic circuits.

"early cards were neither PCB, ...nor were they fiberglass, but made of resin soaked paper" FR-2 is still seen today, usually as stripboard or similar prototyping board

@ChrisH Thanks for the reminder, adding a link is useful.

Re, "Backplane...[lacks] active components." The backplane of the Perq 1 and Perq 2 computers contained just enough active components to implement a hardware state machine from which the chassis serial number could be clocked out in the manner of SMBus (Actual SMBus would not be so named until about fourteen years later.) I struggle to recall, but "just enough components" may, in fact, have been just one component—an 8 bit wide PROM with seven of its data lines fed back into its address lines.

@SolomonSlow :)) Well, there's always the outlier - the one proving the rule :)) Beside that, there are of course intermediate forms where  it get's hard to pick either (rough) categorisation. Like one early 486 I remember being somewhere between all three. Like a backplane it housed different cards (CPU, RAM) using different connectors, but it also had an ISA bus, and many active components (glue logic), including interfaces on that backplane-motherboard-bus hybrid. Isn't it great to look back at so many variation?

Without answering the 'why' - this is standard electronics usage.  I have known 'card' in this sense since the early 1970s, when I first learned which end of a soldering iron to pick up.
Here is an arbitrary example - the Aurora sound-to-light project from Practical Electronics magazine in 1971.  See page 400 in the May issue (page 50 in the PDF file).

All circuits are mounted on individual cards...

The Aurora was built in two boxes, each of which had 8 or so cards in it.  (I am familiar with it, since a friend built one. I think I helped with grunt work like winding pulse transformers).
In my experience, a board may be a standalone thingy, but cards carry the sense of being plugged into something, or connected together.  It's a vague distinction,sure.


...possibly simply the fact they're rectangular and most type of cards are too!?

That strikes me as the most plausible answer - as well as the fact that "cards" are commonly something inserted into (or at least matched with) some kind of holder.
I don't think the word "board" has any profound meaning either beyond the idea of a flattish rectangular lump of something, except the tendency that "boards" are heavier and less mobile than "cards".
So you get formulations like a "motherboard" with "expansion cards".

Technically the matching term for "motherboard" is "daughter board(s)", which was/is used in some contexts, just not with PCs.

In fact the board may have a meaning. Before era of PCBs, one method of making circuits was to mount them on a 63mil thick slice of plywood. Likely why PCBs are still called a board and still 63 mil thick.

Once upon a time, a breadboard could be reused as a breadboard.

My first breadboard circuit was implemented in a length of floorboard.  However I have seen and used circuits implemented on a cardboard support

@mnem, I'm not an electronics professional, so I stand to be corrected on this, but I always had the impression a "daughter board" was merely a subsidiary board made as a distinct part but connected to a motherboard somehow - maybe even soldered, and maybe without which the motherboard doesn't function at all. Not necessarily something auxiliary in an inessential way, and mobile in a way that is readily pluggable or insertable, which (together with a squarish or moderately rectangular shape) is the stronger contextual connotation of a "card".

@Frog, now a "card-board" support just throws everything into confusion haha!

(63mil being 63 thousandths of an inch (0.063in) - about 1.6 millimetres - not 63 millimetres!)

@mnem I worked in IT from 1997 to 2022 and anecdotally, "cards" were always perpendicular to the motherboard, but "daughterboards" were always parallel to the board or card they were attached to. There were daughterboards for sophisticated RAID controllers that would store the configuration in NVRAM so if the controller failed you could move the configuration daughterboard to a replacement controller and restart the array without data loss.

@dave (re: breadboards) I have a server on my home network with the hostname "kardbord", because when I first turned up the system ~20 years ago its temporary 'case' was a cardboard box the motherboard and PSU sat in. (It's still conceptually the same machine, though a Ship-of-Theseus level of upgrades have left the system with no original parts remaining. It even has a case now!)

@ToddWilcox I don't know that I'd want to get too picky about the orientation, though it's true that daughterboards most often end up parallel to the main board. (Then again, a slot riser can leave cards mounted parallel. As can laptop M.2 / mini-PCIe slots.) The attachment method is more of a differentiator — cards go into standardized slots that sit on a bus and have a communication protocol, whereas a daughterboard gets plugged into a unique attachment point — usually one or more 2×N pin headers — that acts as a direct board-to-board connector.

With all due respect to the other answers here attempting to explain the terminology from an electronics point of view, my instincts tell me that's likely not the full picture of it.
Terms for new pieces of equipment are often hit upon by analogy to familiar, everyday objects, and the way that expansion cards are mounted into both PC form factors and, before that, rackmount industrial equipment likely reminded early adopters of the handling of literal paper cards in some manner. (Possibly playing cards, possibly not.)
For example, here's an image of a 1978 Milton Bradley game called "Rack-O" that I think we can all agree bears more than a passing resemblance to the sort of equipment we're talking about:

This particular set is ca. 1978, but the game was in production since at least the early 1960s.
I'm NOT in any way claiming that this exact game gave rise to the term "expansion card". Merely that the image of sliding literal cards into slots, or lining them up in racks, was probably a fairly common one 3/4 of a century ago, much more common than it would be today. The peripheral cards in a modular PC chassis, or a rackmount card cage, were likely to have been highly reminiscent of actual paper cards, to the people working with them.

Downvoting as this is pure speculation.

Did you downvote Raffzahn's answer too? (It was interesting, but just as speculative as to the origin of the nomenclature "card".)

The answer might be improved by pointing out that people have been calling small flat rectangular objects cards for centuries, and cards have been put in slots for at least a hundred years, probably longer.
The basic answer, that it's an obvious and natural name for a small flat object, is pretty hard to dispute.

Why were playing cards called "cards"?  :-)

@barbecue: The game pictured bears a stronger resemblance to many kinds of backplane-based systems than many card-holders of years past.  Most kinds of card holders I can think of would either be designed to display one card, or would have slots or affordances which could hold stacks of cards, and few would hold cards at an angle of 90 degrees.

@dave it's likely that playing cards were the original meaning in English, and other meanings emerged later.  https://www.etymonline.com/word/card

Wiktionary says that "card" can mean any flat rectangular piece of stiff paper, plastic etc. Which a PCB is.
It also mentions that paper card is thinner and more flexible than a paper board (e.g. book covers, board games). Also paper cards are thinner than cardboard.
Before the era of printed circuit boards, one method of making circuits was to mount components on on a 63mil thick slice of plywood.
Likely why PCBs are still called a board and still 63 mil thick.
